# how to implement caching in WCF REST web service in .net 3.5

Tags: wcf, web-services, caching, .net-3.5

I've created a custom WCF Rest web service in a sharepoint site which uses .net 3.5 only not 4
, I found that [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970492/how-to-do-wcf-rest-caching) , [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) talked about [REST Starter Kit](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20REST&ProjectName=aspnet) but I found that it's no longer supported .

Any ideas about how to implement caching in this situation ?

Thanks.

Comment: Caching of what? The whole reponse?

Comment: @OliverWeichhold caching of a method's query result in the web service

Comment: @OliverWeichhold yes database query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[System.Web.Caching.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is your friend. For Framework 4.0 or higher use the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or the [ObjectCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about [Microsoft Enterprise Library Caching Application Block](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647280.aspx&ei=kNYvUZGPDYqD4ASiioHICw&usg=AFQjCNELzC8RP4qyGEgJp64TgCezJZcdmQ&sig2=Z4sFhW320CJ9lc4zFn3jmw&bvm=bv.43148975,d.bGE)